# HttpContext.Current null in WebContentTypeMapper / GetMessageFormatForContentType

Tags: c#, web-services, iis

I want to write a `WebContentTypeMapper` that returns the `WebContentFormat` dependend on the uri path.

Until now I used `HttpContext.Current.Request.PathInfo`.
But if there are large POST-requests with a body of more than 64k then `HttpContext.Current` is null.

I find out that HttpContext.Current is not intended to be used there. But it works in all other cases when the request ist only some kb small.

Is there any other way to find out the path of the current request in `GetMessageFormatForContentType()`?

```
public class RawContentTypeMapper : WebContentTypeMapper
{
    public override WebContentFormat GetMessageFormatForContentType(string contentType)
    {
        string pathInfo;
        try
        {
            pathInfo = HttpContext.Current.Request.PathInfo;
        }
        catch (NullReferenceException e)
        {
            // This happens for large POST requests
            pathInfo = ...please help!
        }
        switch (pathInfo)
        {
            case "/abc/path1":
            case "/abc/path2":
                return WebContentFormat.Raw;
            default:
                return WebContentFormat.Default; // No change to default behavior
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to expand the value of IIS manager->Configuration editor->system.webServer/serverRuntime/uploadReadAheadSize? Because the limit of this value is about 46k

Comment: I didn´t know about it. It has the default value of 49152.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a solution now. Consisting of several changes:

I changed the `RawContentTypeMapper` to always return `WebContentFormat.Raw`

**Web.config:**

- Added a copy of the binding which uses the `RawContentTypeMapper` and removed the `contentTypeMapper` attribute. So it uses a default mapper.
- Added an endpoint to each address ("abc/path1"...) with the binding that uses the RawContentTypeMapper.
- Added an endpoint to the base address "abc" with the default binding.

**IMySourceCode.cs:** and **MySourceCode.cs:**

Made a new `OperationContract` with `UriTemplate = ""`. There I check the `HttpContext.Current.Request.PathInfo` for "abc/path1/", "abc/path2/"... and call the original OperationContract methods.

For that all OperationContracts must have the same signature (here void MyMethod(Stream data)).

Added **Global.asax** to rewrite path "abc/path1" to "abc/path1/"...:

```
    protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var pathInfo = HttpContext.Current.Request.PathInfo.ToLowerInvariant();
        if (pathInfo.StartsWith("/abc/"))
        {
            foreach (var s in new[] { "/abc/path1", "/abc/path2" })
            {
                if (pathInfo == s)
                {
                    var rawUrl = HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl.ToLower(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                    HttpContext.Current.RewritePath($"{rawUrl}/");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```